# How can I calculate the $Y$ value of a point on a linear line at specific angle, based on that points $X$ value?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Say I have a Cartesian coordinate system, and draw a line starting at $(x,y) = (0,0)$ at an angle $N$.

If I know the values $x$ and $N$ of a point on that line, how can i calculate the $y$ value?

First post my apologies for bad formatting.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I hope you stay and contribute to the site.

Comment: The quotient $y/x$ is the tangent of $N$ (assuming you are measuring $N$ with respect to the positive part of the $X$-axis). Therefore, $y=x\tan(N)$.

Comment: +1, the OP actually solved the problem in the comments to the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates of the point with radius $r$ and angle $N$ are $(x,y) = (r \cos N, r \sin N)$. So given $x,N$ you can compute $r = x/\cos N$ and then compute $y$. Can you finish it?

---

**UPDATE**

Since $r = x/\cos N$ we have
$$
y = r \sin N = \frac{x \sin N}{\cos N} = x \tan N.
$$
In your example you seem to be using $x = 4$ and $N = \pi/4 \approx 0.7854$, so $\tan (\pi/4) = 1$ and $y = x \tan N = 4 \cdot 1 = 4$. So your approximation seems correct.

Comment: Its pretty late where I am, but ill try and have a solution by some point tomorrow. geometry has never been my strong suit, I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Electron-Capture +1, no problem, please post your progress in the comments and I will try to help you along as I can.

Comment: I think i found a solution, N=0.785398, X=4. r = 4/ cos 0.785398 = 5.65685332518. (5.65685424 sin 0.785398) = 3.9999993397.          ∴ Y = 3.9999993397. Is my mathematics correct? or am I missing something? again, i greatly appreciate your patience.

Comment: @Electron-Capture +1, correct again, thanks for trying. See update to my answer as well